# Firefox : window.print() block window.history.back() function

Tags: firefox, printing, block, history, back

I've got a problem when I want to go back with `window.location.back()` after using `window.print()`.

When I click on my Print button, I'm redirected to a new page with the document to print and the print pop-in appear. On Chrome and IE, when we click on print into the pop-in, `window.location.back()` is triggered but not in Firefox ...

```
timeout(function () {
   window.print()
   window.history.back();
}, 500);
```

I've tried some possible solution like `window.onafterprint` or `window.onbeforeprint` events, 
`window.location.go(-1)`, but none works on Firefox.

Also, if I remove the `window.print()` line, `window.location.back()` works fine.

I've got no other solutions, could you help me ?

Comment: are you sure you are not talking about `setTimeout` rather than `timeout` ? Or, can you provide the simplest html file for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't mean `setTimeout`?

Using Firefox, with the following html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.print();
            window.history.back();
        }, 500);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>Nothing here</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

seem to work just fine.

500ms after loading, the print dialog shows, then, it goes back in history.

Comment: Timeout is an angularjs function whose do the same thing but I tried your solution and she doesn't work unfortunatelly.

Comment: the exact code i wrote does work as is. make sure you have something in your browser back history - with firefox it will go to whatever page is set when opening your browser